# how to upload recorded audio by flutter_sound package to server using Dio in flutter?

Tags: android, django, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I am building a chat application in Django and it has a mobile app (using Flutter) as well which consumes the RESTFUL API of the web app. The web app is completed but stuck with sending recorded audio by flutter_sound package to the server using Dio.